# is it possible to use spring-integration with apache kafka and apache spark?

Tags: spring-integration, apache-spark, apache-kafka

i was wondering if it is posible to use spring-integration with apache kafka and apache spark. I have been looking for in http://forum.spring.io and nothing appears, but i may see in stackoverflow that people is using it, at least apache kafka with spring-integration. Can anyone share a minimal project or something?

The idea is to connect a Kafka Producer feeding apache spark through spring-integration.

My apologies if this question is off topic or something already answered.

Comment: is spring essential, because you can feed spark directly from kafka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [Apache Kafka Spring Integration Extension here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions).

Comment: Thank you Gary, i already saw this extension. It is being incubated, but thank you.

Comment: Can you please help me understand is there any good reason using Spring with Kafka. Of course basics of spring benefits like dependency injection is a plus but I wonder things relative to Spring for kafka.